# How to get max value using vb.net and mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a column (copy_no1) in mysql with data

```
301
67
1234
2345
3433-a
6543
456
2344
```

In this data --- the biggest Number is --- 6543
How to get it from vb.net code?

My code is ----

```
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        Dim rs As MySqlDataReader
        cmd = con.CreateCommand
        'cmd.CommandText = "select MAX(won) from field_copy_no"
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from field_copy_no order by copy_no1"
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rs.Read

            Label9.Text = rs.GetString(3)
            Label10.Text = rs.GetString(4)
        End While
        rs.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
```

By using both the command text, I got the result - 67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just use the `MAX()` function?

```
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim rs As MySqlDataReader
    cmd = con.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "select max(CAST(copy_no1 as UNSIGNED)) as value from field_copy_no"
    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rs.Read
        Label9.Text = rs.GetString(0)
    End While
    rs.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
```

Comment: I am getting error through this code.... error is - you have specified an invalid column ordinal

Comment: Excuseme, `GetString` requires a zero-indexed column number. I'm going to correct it. You should use `rs.GetString(0)`

Comment: Now also I am not getting my exact result... what to do?

Comment: Ahh, could it be that your column is a `varchar`? 67 is the maximum string in the given values... If you want the biggest number, you must cast it to integer values (what could cause an error as you have a value: `3433-a`).